# Can I pass a sub query as table_name in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created on table by joining more than two tables in mysql..
Now I want to use that query to pass as sub query for table name in another query..
Can I use it??

I have three tables and inner joined them with below query..

```
SELECT A.emp_id, B.designation_name, C.dept_name, A.fname, A.lname, A.address, A.city,     A.contactnumber1, A.contactnumber2,
A.email, A.salary, A.dob, A.doj, A.created_on, A.modified_on 
FROM employee_master A
INNER JOIN designation_master B
INNER JOIN depart_master C 
ON A.designation_id = B.id AND A.department_id = C.id
```

Now I want to use this query as sub query for fetching number of rows in table.

Comment: You cannot use result of a query as table name, but you can use perspective, subquery etc. that gives you result you want, without specifing concrete table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but you can select from a select:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
  SELECT A.emp_id, B.designation_name, C.dept_name, A.fname, A.lname, A.address, A.city
       , A.contactnumber1, A.contactnumber2, A.email, A.salary, A.dob, A.doj
       , A.created_on, A.modified_on 
  FROM employee_master A
  JOIN designation_master B
      ON A.designation_id = B.id
  JOIN depart_master C 
      ON A.department_id = C.id
) AS T 
WHERE ...
```

You can "name" the query by creating a view:

```
CREATE VIEW WHATEVER AS
    SELECT A.emp_id, B.designation_name, C.dept_name, A.fname, A.lname, A.address, A.city
         , A.contactnumber1, A.contactnumber2, A.email, A.salary, A.dob, A.doj
         , A.created_on, A.modified_on 
    FROM employee_master A
    JOIN designation_master B
        ON A.designation_id = B.id
    JOIN depart_master C 
        ON A.department_id = C.id
```

Then it is possible to reference that:

```
SELECT ...
FROM WHATEVER
WHERE ...
```